Set Spotfire Graph Y Axis Range
I have a question as I am lacking in knowledge of Spotfire.
I would like to know how to change the y-axis range of multiple combination charts.
I want the y-axis range of multiple charts to change when the slider is changed in the text area.
Or, I would like the y-axis range to be set to a value that is 10% lower than the automatically determined minimum value.
I know that the default value for the axis range is none, so I tried entering things like none-10, but it didn't work.
Any ideas?
